# Why is effective mass a tensor?

Tags: condensed-matter, lagrangian-formalism, mass, field-theory

So I came across the [effective mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)) concept for solids the other day. It was mentioned that the effective mass is a tensor and may have different values in different directions. However, this is stark contrast to ordinary mass which is direction independent (as far as I know). So how do we physically explain this direction dependence of electrons (holes) mass inside a solid? Is it called "mass" just because it has the dimensions of mass? Or is it just a mathematical tool without any physical significance?

Comment: @Poutnik https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)

Comment: I don't if its obsolete or abandoned but still its in my course of study. When you inertia of object depends on direction of force, why and how does it depend? Why don't we see this dependency outside solids? Is it because of periodic potentials or Bloch's theorem?

Comment: It’s because a solid’s crystal lattice means that environment for the particle is not isotropic.

Comment: Thanks @G.Smith. I have gone through the article in wikipedia and it raises more doubts than it clears. It says "mass it seems to have". What is the meaning of seems to have? Does it mean that effective mass is purely mathematical and have nothing to do with the real mass?

Comment: My expertise is not in solid state physics, and I think you need an answer from someone who has that expertise. I don’t understand how or whether the effective mass inside the solid is related to the actual mass in vacuum. But I do not think that it is correct to consider effective mass as purely mathematical. It *does* have physical significance.

Comment: “Seems to have” means that this effective mass determines the rate of change of the group velocity in response to a force, from my reading of the article. To me, that means it has physical significance.

Comment: The tensor part you can think of as a mathematical convenience :" two vectors a tensor make" and it is easier to manipulate mathematically. why the effective mass is defined like that in solid state  physics it needs a solid state physicist  to explain. In general I would agree with the isotropy mentioned by gsmith.

Comment: Particles or particle like phenomena in solid state physics are often dealt as if they had been ideal gas particles with equivalent would be mass, having the same kinematic properties. Therefore an electron in solid is taken as a quasiparticle ( similarly as a hole ) with mass higher than a real electron, in context of its kinematics. It's  effective inertial mass is determined by the lattice interaction and is anisotropic, as the lattice is anisotropic, therefore it is tensor.

Answer (score 4):

Your surprise for a tensor mass is originating from a misconception: to assume that the usual point particle mechanics is the "natural" mechanics and everything less usual (i.e. beyond the introductory physics level) requires a special explanation in terms of it.

Actually things can be stated in a different, more general way. Assuming that a basic tenet of Newtonian mechanics is a linear relation between force and acceleration, taking into account the vector character of both quantities, the most general relation among them should be a tensor relation. It is an experimental fact that for point particles at low energy such a tensor is diagonal and only one parameter is enough. However, even without quantum mechanics, there are cases where the necessity of a more general linear relation shows up.

One case is that of constrained systems. It is well known that one of the most effective way to deal with them is to use the constraint equations to reduce the umber of degrees of freedom and this is efficiently done within the Lagrangian formalism. The passage from the usual descritpion in  terms of three-dimensional position vectors ${\bf r_i}$ to generalized coordinates $q_{\alpha}$ implies that in general the kinetic energy term has the form 
$$
T = \sum_{\alpha \beta} m_{\alpha \beta}\dot q_{\alpha} \dot q_{\beta}
$$
where $m_{\alpha \beta}$ is a  positive definite matrix.

Also in relativistic mechanics, the relation between acceleration and force may be written as a tensor relation, provided a mass tensor depending on velocity is introduced.

The common feature of such different systems is the non-alignment between acceleration and force.

It is then not completely weird that the kinetic energy term of a quantum mechanics system could show a similar anisotropy.

Answer (score 3):

Effective mass $m_{\ast}$ is just a constant that shows up in the dispersion relation $\epsilon(\mathbf{k})$ of an energy band. Consider a one-dimensional band with dispersion $\epsilon(k)$. Expanding near a minimum of $\epsilon$
\begin{align}
\epsilon(k) \approx \epsilon_0 + \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m_{\ast}}
\end{align}
It's defined by analogy to the quantum mechanical energy of a free particle of mass $m$,
\begin{align}
E(k) = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}.
\end{align}
For example, consider a one-dimensional tight-binding model with dispersion
\begin{align}
\epsilon(k) = -2 t\cos(ka).
\end{align}
Taylor expanding $\epsilon$ near $k=0$ we get
\begin{align}
\epsilon(k)\approx -2t + tk^2 a^2.
\end{align}
so that the effective mass is
\begin{align}
m_{\ast}= \frac{\hbar^2}{2ta^2}.
\end{align}
In higher dimensions, the dispersion relation can be more complicated. If the dispersion is isotropic (the same in every direction), then
\begin{align}
\epsilon(\mathbf{k}) = \epsilon_0 + \frac{\hbar^2 |\mathbf{k}|^2}{2m_{\ast}}.
\end{align}
However, you could have a dispersion where the constants in front of different components of $\mathbf{k}$ are different, e.g.
\begin{align}
\epsilon(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{\hbar^2}{2}\left(\frac{k_x^2}{m_x} + \frac{k_y^2}{m_y}\right)
\end{align}
Such a dispersion could arise from, e.g., a tight-binding model in which the hopping parameters or lattice constants in each direction are different. You could even have a dispersion with cross-terms between the components of $\mathbf{k}$, e.g.
\begin{align}
\epsilon(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{\hbar^2}{2}\left(\frac{k_x^2}{m_1} + \frac{k_x k_y}{m_2} + \frac{k_y^2}{m_3}\right)
\end{align}
In general, the dispersion (to quadratic order, and dropping the constant) will be
\begin{align}
\epsilon(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{\hbar^2}{2}\sum_{a,b}h_{ab} k_a k_b
\end{align}
for a tensor $h_{ab}$ — the inverse of the effective mass tensor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it did not answer my query. You say that effective mass is just a constant, does it mean that it is called "mass" just because it has the dimensions of mass?

Comment: Basically, yes. It also "acts like" a mass in that it affects things like how the particles/holes in a band respond to electric forces, or the cyclotron frequency. The anisotropy (direction dependence) of the effective mass tells you (for example) that electric response along different directions may be different.

Comment: Whenever someone says 'basically' I stop listening, because I know they really don't care about explaining themselves well

Comment: @MondoDuke I admit to feeling little cause for concern at losing at listener to something so arbitrary as that.

Comment: @d_b good point, sorry about that